# Azure Error: SSL Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED when using mongoose

Tags: node.js, azure, npm

Have a locally running node.js app using mongoose to do crud with mlab's mongodb. No problems

I post my code to github, and then tell Azure to host my app as a webapp, which I have done many times without mongoose.

As best I can tell, Azure does an npm install on my package.json file on my behalf as it installs my app into one of their web server hosts.

If I comment out these lines in my users.js route:

```
//var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

all is well, Azure runs my app.

If I do not comment them out, I get this error written in the Azure log:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose
npm ERR! Error: SSL Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
```

In an effort to fix this in my package.json file, I have:
[1]  forced azure to use this version of node

```
"engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x"
  },
```

[2] tried to force to a current version

```
 "mongoose": "^5.3.11",
```

[3] tried to force negotiator to this version as GitHub was complaining about a security issue with negotiator

`"negotiator": ">=0.6.1",`

I would REALLY like to continue to have Azure run my web apps using GitHub, and not get into the Azure command line stuff to install my bits, so I don't have much control of the installation.   There is something about Mongoose that is bad.

thanks

Comment: `"node": "0.8.x"` - That's a really old node version. The error is from `npm` since it does not like the changes to secure repo's. You "really should" use a more modern `node` and `npm`. There are workarounds ( turning off SSL ), but that's just a "band aid". You'll never be able to get commercial support for an old version, so it's not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is updating to the newer certificates' definitions.
This version of **[config-defs.js](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/attachment.cgi?id=1416575)** might do the trick (usually located under **/deps/npm/lib/utils**).

You might also need to update that file with an additional certificate as described **[here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20191#issuecomment-392330961)**

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, that might be useful for someone, but not for me.

Comment: I install node.js and npm, express an app, write a few lines in a route, and send that up to GitHub, where my Azure web services is pointed to deploy from, and it works.  Unless I try to pull in mongoose in my package.json file.  So where in that simple process would I see a config-defs.js?  Its not in my project, and nothing with that name is in my package.json.

Comment: Again, I don't get to build this once I tell Azure to run it, Azure builds it, so I can't inject commands or steps in that process.  (well, at least I can't, and I don't want to make this whole thing too complicated for my students.) Why does ever other package that I have been using by including in my package.json file just work and mongoose does not?  It would seem to a problem with their code?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Neil Lunn  fixed it, thanks.  I was having problems running v10.x.x of node, and tried dropping back to V8.x.x to get around a breaking change in v10, and I screwed up the name of V8.   "node": "0.8.x"  does not get V8, 8.10.0 does and all is well.